# Pandas strftime running slow within multiprocessing

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, multiprocessing, strftime

I'm seeing a behavior when working with time stamps within pandas DataFrames. The project I'm working on requires I read in data, convert a date string to a date-time object, later the the date-time object is converted back to a string with a different format. I do the conversion using `data_frame.dt.strftime()`. When I move call my function using a multiprocessing pool, rather than calling it directly, I see a big slowdown when converting from a date-time to string. Below, I include some timing measurements, with and without multiprocessing. The code used to run these tests is at the bottom of the post.

```
No multiprocessing
Time to read: 0.286389112473
Time to convert to string: 0.160706996918
Total time: 0.4490878582 s

With multiprocessing
Time to read: 0.287585020065
Time to convert to string: 6.90422201157
Total time: 7.23801398277 s
```

This test shows that there is little difference in the time it takes to read in the DataFrame (converting string to date-time), but converting back out to a string takes much longer when calling from within multiprocessing. Is there a reason for this? Is there a way to work around it?

Edit:

Just to clarify, in this example, I'm intentionally supplying a single process to the multiprocessing pool. I'm interested in the difference in runtime when calling the testing function directly or via multiprocessing.

I certainly expect a small amount of overhead related to transferring data to the worker process, but I'm seeing added inefficiency when processing the DataFrame. That is, when I process the same data, with the same code, providing the same resources, it takes 40x longer to convert the column from date-time objects to strings. I take this hit again if I try and write the DataFrame to a file using `to_csv()`

---

My system configuration is the following:

- OS: Mac
- Python release: 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0
- Pandas version: 0.18.1
- Multiprocessing version: 0.70a1

Code to run timing test:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def test_timing(file_name):
    date_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
    date_parser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format=date_format)

    tic = time.time()
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name,
                     names=['date_time'],
                     parse_dates=['date_time'],
                     date_parser=date_parser,
                     nrows=50000)
    print('Time to read: {}'.format(time.time() - tic))

    tic = time.time()
    date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
    df['date'] = df['date_time'].dt.strftime(date_format)
    print('Time to convert to string: {}'.format(time.time() - tic))

    return df


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print('No multiprocessing')
tic = time.time()
df = test_timing('sample_data.csv')
# print(df.head())
print('Total time: {} s'.format(time.time() - tic))
print()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print('With multiprocessing')
tic = time.time()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
df = pool.map(test_timing, ['sample_data.csv'])
# print(df[0].head())
print('Total time: {} s'.format(time.time() - tic))
```

Comment: After doing a few more tests, it appears this happens in environment on my laptop, but not when working on our linux cluster (using the system linux). I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood the problem at first (and then again a bit). I ran this code on linux and the times don't differ significantly. And have no idea what is going on. So, I think my answer isn't useful at all and I'll delete it. (To be completely sure that it's nothing to do with `print`, I'd place `time.time()` outside of it.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try installing another python distribution to see if it's something specific to the anaconda release for mac or something deeper on my computer.